# Ansible/Tower - Match 'hosts' variable (inventory group name) by supplying a var from the group_vars file?

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory, ansible-tower

I have a project running in Tower whereby using Survey I prompt the user for a selection;

Right now it is a list of group-names supplied as possibilities that will match a group defined in inventory as well as a vars file under `group_vars` titled with its name.

Main play reads like:

```
---
  - name: Project Title
    hosts: "{{ site_code }}"
```

So if `office` is selected it will pass the group `office` and grab info from `group_vars\office.yml`

Since the groups have codes attached they are only relevant to my team;

However within each vars file is an attribute of Location that has the real name of the office/site being used and would be ideal if users were prompted with these names, which then translate into the group-name for usage within `hosts`.

I would rename all of the groups to a logical title, but some are large, have dashes etc. and the limitations of an inventory group-name is restrictive in this particular setup.

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: Further to this, I am able to generate a list from all groups and produce the variables I need in the format: 
`ok: [sfooff01-host -> 127.0.0.1] => {
    "msg": [
        "code: sfooff01", 
        "city: San Francisco"
    ]
}
ok: [duboff01-host -> 127.0.0.1] => {
    "msg": [
        "code: duboff01", 
        "city: Dublin"
    ]
}
ok: [blroff01-host -> 127.0.0.1] => {
    "msg": [
        "code: blroff01", 
        "city: Bangalore"
    ]
}`

Comment: But because I delegate to localhost and produce a list with all the same variable names if I do a when condition to match the site I want, it does this ont he correct host but produces "VARIABLE NOT DEFINED" for the rest and using the correct one is proving difficult.